# Cocos2D CCTransitionPageTurn From Left to Right

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can I make `CCTransitionPageTurn` curl the page in a mirrored way to how it is currently implemented (as if you want you are flipping the page of an Arabic book). 
Here is `CCActionPageTurn3D`, where would I invert an angle or use `(1024 - x)`? :-)

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)time
{
    float tt = MAX( 0, time - 0.25f );
    float deltaAy = ( tt * tt * 500);
    float ay = -100 - deltaAy;

    float deltaTheta = - (float) M_PI_2 * sqrtf( time) ;
    float theta = /*0.01f*/ + (float) M_PI_2 +deltaTheta;

    float sinTheta = sinf(theta);
    float cosTheta = cosf(theta);

    for( int i = 0; i <=gridSize_.x; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j <= gridSize_.y; j++ )
        {
            // Get original vertex
            ccVertex3F  p = [self originalVertex:ccg(i,j)];

            float R = sqrtf(p.x*p.x + (p.y - ay) * (p.y - ay));
            float r = R * sinTheta;
            float alpha = asinf( p.x / R );
            float beta = alpha / sinTheta;
            float cosBeta = cosf( beta );

            // If beta > PI then we've wrapped around the cone
            // Reduce the radius to stop these points interfering with others
            if( beta <= M_PI)
                p.x = ( r * sinf(beta));
            else
            {
                // Force X = 0 to stop wrapped
                // points
                p.x = 0;
            }

            p.y = ( R + ay - ( r*(1 - cosBeta)*sinTheta));

            // We scale z here to avoid the animation being
            // too much bigger than the screen due to perspectve transform
            p.z = (r * ( 1 - cosBeta ) * cosTheta) / 7; // "100" didn't work for

            // Stop z coord from dropping beneath underlying page in a transition
            // issue #751               
            if( p.z<0.5f )
                p.z = 0.5f;

            // Set new coords
            [self setVertex:ccg(i,j) vertex:p];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use CCTransitionPageTurn  and put *backwards* attribute to YES.

Example

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if (location.x < (screenSize.width * .25) && location.y < (screenSize.height * .25)) {

    CCTransitionPageTurn *transition = [CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1.75 scene:[Page1 scene] backwards:YES];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];
    }

    if (location.x > (screenSize.width * .75) && location.y < (screenSize.height * .25)) {

    CCTransitionPageTurn *transition = [CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1.75 scene:[Page3 scene] backwards:NO];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];
    }
    }
```

Taken from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2454&p=15611)